# How come I can't delete a entity in Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

Here is my code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class m(db.Model):
s = db.StringProperty()
k = m(s='To be deleted')
k.put()
print k.key()
db.delete(k.key())
print k.s
```

and this is the output i am getting:

```
aghkZXZ-YmxvZ3IOCxIBbRiAgICAgPC7Cgw
To be deleted
```

Comment: And what makes you think that this entity has not been deleted in the Datastore?

Comment: Have you checked the datastore to see if it has been deleted?

Comment: you download the entity, then ask the server to delete said entity.... then you check your DOWNLOADED entity.  It will of course be there.  As other people are saying, check your datastore again, the entity won't be there

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the output:

`print k.key()` gives you the first line `(aghkZXZ-YmxvZ3IOCxIBbRiAgICAgPC7Cgw)` which is the key of the entity you asked to be printed.

And `print k.s` gives you exactly what you asked for, the value of the property `s` which you set to `"to be deleted"` in the line `k = m(s='To be deleted')`. You really need to check the datastore to see if the entity was deleted.

Go to https://appengine.google.com, click on the application, and then in `Dashboard` view, click on `Datastore Viewer`

[image]

Comment: No need to go to the datastore viewer: OP can just try to do a get for that key - `db.get(k.key())` - and it should return None rather than an object.